# is there a way that I can run test classes of different maven sub_modules on a same jvm thread?

Tags: java, maven, jvm

I have a `maven project` and it has several `sub_modules`,
the directory structure like this:

> - project
>
>   - pom.xml
>   - sub_module1
>
>     - pom.xml
>     - src
>
>       - test1
>   - sub_module2
>
>     - pom.xml
>     - src
>
>       - test2
>   - sub_module3
>
>     - pom.xml
>     - src
>
>       - test3

---

I know that through **mvn test** command the `test class` of *test1* or *test2* or *test3*  will run on a same `jvm thread` respectively by default.

---

now I want to all `test class` of *test1* and *test2* and *test3* can **run on a same jvm thread**. I dont know whether there exist a solution for this requirement.

Comment: First question which comes to my mind: Why do you need such thing? are those tests unit tests ?